# How to check the dict results if the input is only part of the keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict and input like that, and now I want to it can search the input even though it is only part of key words, so how to solve it?

```
input = "a"
dict = {'aaa':111,'bbb':222,'ccc':333}
print(dict[input])
```

P.S Assuming there is no conflict between input and dict keywords, for example,

```
input ='a'
dict = {'aaa':111,'abc':222}
```

is impossible

Comment: If the input is part of multiple keys, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there can be no conflict, or if you're happy to take the first key that matches the input if there is, you could search the keys to find one which starts with the input string:

```py
input = "a"
dic = {'aaa':111,'bbb':222,'ccc':333}
dic[[k for k in dic.keys() if k.startswith(input)][0]]
```

Output:

```
111
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (Python 3.x)

```
input = "a"
dict = {'aaa':111,'bbb':222,'ccc':333}

def find(inp, dct):
    for k in dct.keys():
        if inp.lower() in k.lower():
            return dct[k]
    return "NOT FOUND"

print(find(input, dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way (although not the simplest one) would be subclassing *dict*.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


class LooseKeyDict(dict):
    def __matching_keys(self, key):
        return [e for e in self.keys() if key in e]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        mc = self.__matching_keys(key)
        if not mc or len(mc) > 1:
            raise KeyError(key)
        return super().__getitem__(mc[0])


def main(*argv):
    d0 = LooseKeyDict({"aaa": 111, "bbb": 222, "ccc": 333})
    print(d0["a"])
    print(d0["aaa"])
    try:
        print(d0["aaa1"])
    except KeyError as ke:
        print("KeyError:", ke)

    d1 = LooseKeyDict({"aaa": 111, "abc": 222})
    try:
        print(d1["a"])
    except KeyError as ke:
        print("KeyError:", ke)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```py
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071851970]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> 222
> 222
> KeyError: 'aaa1'
> KeyError: 'a'
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- This is only for the *read* part. If you want to also do it for *write* (or *delete*), you'd have to also override *__setitem__* (or *__delitem__*). More details on [[Python.Docs]: Data model](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#data-model)
- Don't name your variables *input* or *dict*, as you're shadowing built-in names